# For LibGDX Android games, how to limit APK size when PNGs of different sizes exist for the same image, but only 1 that fits the screen is loaded?

Tags: android, libgdx, apk, resolution, filesize

For example, I have 4 PNG files for the same background image. If the device is a tablet with very high resolution, the program will load only the largest PNG (2400 x 3200) for that image. On the other hand, if the device is a phone with only 600 x 800 pixel resolution, then only the smallest PNG will be loaded, making the other 3 PNG files unnecessary for that device. In such a case, how do I make sure the APK for that device does not contain the unnecessary PNGs?

I am making a game with lots and lots of graphics.

Comment: In situation like this I'm adding to apk the image with highest resolution. Only other solution I'm aware of is to have different apk for different resolutions. That would meat that you'll i.e. have more than one version of your game on Play Store. But first solution is easier to maintain - only one version to take care of.